# RXJS How convert observable<T>[] to observable<T[]>?

Tags: rxjs

How convert array of observable to observable of array?

```
  func f1: string -> Observable<T> 
  o: Observable<string[]>
  o.map( x => x.map( y=> f1(y)))
  .mergeAll() 

  return is Observable<T>[].
```

How can i get it ?

Answer (score 0):

Correct solution :

```
  o.mergeMap( x=> Observable.from(
             x.map( y => f1(y) ).mergeAll().toArray()
          )
       )
```

or if not exist mergeMap():

```
    o.map( x=> Observable.from(
             x.map( y => f1(y) ).mergeAll().toArray()
          )
       ).mergeAll()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.